# Building C# lib

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build this code with control + alt + f5:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Formater
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public async Task <object> Invoke (object input)
        {
            return ".NET";
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm receiving this error:

"A Project with an output type of Class Library cannot be started directly.

In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project."

What could be the problem? I was searching SOF question and i found several solutions, but none of them is working.

Thanks.

Comment: F5 is not for building, it is for running. Use F6 for building.

Answer (score 4):

> What could be the problem?

As you say:

> A Project with an output type of Class Library cannot be started directly

It goes on - if you bother reading:

> In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution 
>   which references the library project. Set the executable project as
>   the startup project.

This is all clear english. A class library (dll) has no entry point and can not be started. It is a library to be used in a program.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are building a library (.dll) Visual Studio doesn't know how to run this. Visual Studio can only run programs (.exe) or websites that are loaded by a web server (among other things).

The solution offered by Visual Studio basically means that you must reference your library in some other other program to be able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You are building a class library which has not any entry point or main method. You can not run class library alone, you can only build it, for running this class library you either have to add it will a `console app` or `win form` or any of the .net application